# EMF reader for USB

Tags: usb

I'm looking for electromagnetic field reader as demonstrated in the [this documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8VyUsVOic0&t=816) (shown below):

[image: screenshot of EMF reader from Water Memory documentary 2014]

Or some similar device which can do the same (measure EMF fingerprint of the placed object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm finding this hilarious. The pseudoscience is stunning. That device is a pretty standard microphone that was used for attaching to a landline. The proper name escapes me (I'll update) but you can find it as a telephone suction cup [microphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0034I75IK) for between 5-20 dollars on amazon. I am unable to identify the *sound card* he is using for the capture, and the software he's using seems to be [wavelab](http://www.steinberg.net/en/products/wavelab/start.html). Any good soundcard should work for this I suspect

I'd note those things are good fun, and he might be picking up noise off of his power lead. I'm unsure what the seemingly quarter inch connector is leading off of the sound device.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that its pickup coil is sensitive to magnetic fields between about 300-3000Hz, so it can picks up sound from any objects emitting electro magnetic power. Pretty interesting.